# How does binary data get generated?

Tags: signal

How does hardware generate binary codes?

For instance, keyboard generates scancode "1E"  when I press "A".   But how?

P.S.: I assume software only interprets and processes binary data (not generates it)

Comment: You have a basic theoretical [electronics question](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_circuit), not a [problem using your computer](http://superuser.com/faq). P.S. In a digital computer, ALL data is binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit oversimplified, but you can think of it as the `A` key being wired to a circuit that produces the combination of signals that the computer (actually the keyboard controller) interprets as `1E`.